# D3.js Add 'line' on a timeline that already has circles

Tags: javascript, d3.js, timeline

I am new to D3.js and I have been working on graphs which share a common timeline.

[Image of my current timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZWX4.jpg)

Data comes with a Date which I turn into a unix timestamp.
The time line is draggable and all 'circles' work as expected and they follow the timeline. 
My problem starts when I try to add a 'line'. The shape is stack at the end of the timeline and doesn't follow the change in time. Ideally I want to be able to draw a thick 'line' that will be placed on the timeline according to a starting and ending date.

Here is my code for the circles:

```
function drawMarkers(dataset, x, y, radius, hoverRadius) {

  let pointGroup = that.g.selectAll('.point-group');
  let tooltipFormat = that.tooltipData();

  pointGroup.selectAll('.marker')
  .data(dataset, function(d) { return d.ts; })
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .classed('marker', true)
  .attr('cx', function(d) { return x(d.ts); })
  .attr('cy', function(d) { return y(d.value); })
  .attr('r', function(d){ return radius; })
  .each(that.markerClass)
  .on('mouseover', function(d) {
    tooltip.show(d, tooltipFormat.keyFn, tooltipFormat.dataFn);
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .attr('r', function(d){ return hoverRadius; });
  })
  .on('mouseout', function(d) {
    tooltip.hide();
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .attr('r', function(d){ return radius; })
  })
  .on('click', function (d) {
      // console.log('marker chart clicked', d);
      if (markerClicked) {
        console.log(d);
        markerClicked(d);
      }
  });
 }
```

This is the change I tried to render the lines:

```
function drawMarkers(dataset, x, y, radius, hoverRadius) {

  let pointGroup = that.g.selectAll('.point-group');
  let tooltipFormat = that.tooltipData();

  pointGroup.selectAll('.marker')
  .data(dataset, function(d) { return d.ts; })
  .enter()
  .append('line')
  .classed('marker', true)
  .classed('markerRect', true)
  .attr("x1", function(d) { return x(d.ts); })
  .attr("y1", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
  .attr("x2", function(d) { return x(d.ts2); })
  .attr("y2", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
  .each(that.markerClass)
  .on('mouseover', function(d) {
    tooltip.show(d, tooltipFormat.keyFn, tooltipFormat.dataFn);
  })
  .on('mouseout', function(d) {
    tooltip.hide();
  })
  .on('click', function (d) {
      // console.log('marker chart clicked', d);
      if (markerClicked) {
        console.log(d);
        markerClicked(d);
      }
  });
 }
```

Any advice would be really appreciated!

EDIT: My data looks like this (array of objects):

```
[{
  "ts": 1530504433000,
  "ts2": 1531504433000,
  "value": 0,
  "action": "string",
  "_details": {
    "name": "Name",
    "value": 0,
    "even": false,
    "useris": "483",
    "action": "string action"
  }
}]
```

Comment: Hard to answer without full reproducible code (and without knowing what your data looks like), but this `.data(dataset, function(d) { return [d.ts, d.ts2]; })` looks very suspicious especially if your data is an array with objects with properties `ts` and `value`.  Update your question with your data and if you can a complete example.

Comment: Thanx Mark.. I updated my question with my data plus I removed what you mentioned as it was a left over from my previous tries :D

Comment: Hmm... If your data looks like that then your code looks OK, *noting that you'll get a line for each element in your array*.